# Looking for a kid's puzzle, cannot remember title

Tags: geometry, puzzle-identification

I'm looking for a kids' logical puzzle I saw in a Brazilian puzzle magazine several years ago. A farmer had a square farm with four houses and twelve trees and he wanted to divide it between his four daughters. Each daughter had to have three trees and one house on her part of the land. Areas did not need to be the same.

It is NOT this puzzle: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/puzzle-divide-square-land-among-4-sons/, nor this one: http://supercuca.blogspot.com/2011/05/, which have similar premises.

The catch was that the division must be done with two straight lines through the drawing of the land.

I can create a trivial puzzle like that:

```
HTTH
TTTT
TTTT
HTTH
```

(H for houses, T for trees). Two orthogonal lines solved the puzzle. But I recall that the position of houses and trees seemed more random. The drawing was very childlike, with lots of spaces between houses and trees.

Do you know of such a puzzle? I've been searching Google images for some time without success.

Here is a puzzle that is similar to the one I described:

[image: Puzzle]

Split the trees and houses in four regions, each with a house and three trees, using two lines. To create this puzzle I cheated and divided the region before and put the trees and houses on the four regions, which does not need to be the same size.

Is there a name for this type of puzzle? Or at least a broad category, e.g. geometric/visual?

Comment: Many such problems are made by the magazines themselves for just one publication.  You can probably find variants of this but maybe not the exact same problem you saw.

Comment: I think it was drawn just for that issue (similar problems for different issues, all based on the same concept). I was wondering if there was a name for this category of puzzles so I could refine my search.

Comment: They probably belong to the broad category of [spatial awarenes](https://www.wikijob.co.uk/content/aptitude-tests/test-types/spatial-awareness-test), but that's just my opinion.